# Maps kit crashed as soon as the user try to open it

Tags: react-native, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-map-kit

we have issue with hms react native map kit, during development we used cloud device and we don't have issue with showing maps on p40 & m30 devices

Later on some huawei devices user can't open the maps without app crash & closed (Honor 8x & TRT-LX2)

The error contains

> com.huawei.hms.dynamicloader.e[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/user_de/0/com.huawei.android.hsf/modules/external/huawei_module_huaweimaps/some_number/HuaweiMapsProvider.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user_de/0/com.huawei.android.hsf/modules/external/huawei_module_huaweimaps/some_number/HuaweiMapsProvider.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64, /hw_product/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]] couldn't find "libmap.so"

How to solve these?
Thanks for your help

Comment: hi, is there a detailed log about this problem? @Vina

Comment: Could try to clear the HMS Core cache or upgrade the HMS Core APK to the latest version to see if the problem persists .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honor 8x(released in 2018) and TRT-LX2(released in 2017) are old devices. Based on the error msg, it failed to find libmap.so.

You can try to integrate the latest Map kit v6.2.0.301 (2021-11-15,  Added the fallback-full dependencies). For more information: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-sdk-version-change-history-0000001050156688

Or as Shirley mentioned, try to upgrade the latest HMS core and clean cache.

If the above 2 ways are not working, could you share more detailed logs? it will be a great help to debug it quickly.

Comment: We're using react native hms map latest version, and we back to use google maps with old huawei devices, thanks a lot for your help @Zinna

Answer (score 0):

You could try to upgrade HMS Core to the latest version in the AppGallery and try again to see if the issue persists.
If the issue persists, pls provide the complete error logs or send your test APK to the *hmscore@huawei.com* for us to check.

Comment: hi @shirley, we still have issue with location kit event listener not being triggered on m30 & m30 pro.. hms core upgraded and issue still persists and no error show on js side, can you help how we can solve this?